# show tables with like using Java and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i have some jsp file. it has some variables. i want to use these varibles inside a mysql query as follows.

```
String given_session="monsoon";
String given_year="2012";
// note above two will be dynamically added.

ResultSet rs11 = (ResultSet) st11.executeQuery("show tables like '%_Assessment_" + given_session + "_" + given_year+"'");
```

I got the following exception :

```
 java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%_Assessment_Monsoon_2013''
```

Comment: You should read MySQL docs
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html

Comment: Your error message has two single quotes at the end.  Are you sure you're not passing those in your SQL statement?

Answer (score 3):

There is a better and more elegant way.

```
String tableNamePattern  = "%_Assessment_" + session + "_" + year;

DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, null, tableNamePattern, 
                                          null);
while(rs.next()) {
    String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
    ...
}
```

Moreover, you must know the best practices of programming in Java because what you are using in your code is not smart. You can see a lot in [*Java Collected Practices*](http://www.javapractices.com/home/HomeAction.do).